# How to modify all "add another ..." text to one generic text in admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

The `Add another ...` text in the admin forms is basically a bit of a mess in terms of grammar in my language, so i would like to alter them all so it only states `Add another`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can customize `tabular.html`:

copy `tabular.html` from

```
django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/tabular.html
```

to your project in `{your_project}/{your_model}`

in this template you can find `Add another`, and replace it with every word that you want.

Comment: Do you know what may be wrong if the files aren't overrided?

Comment: maybe you put it in wrong place? check your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in `settings.py`